# Is the Helical Engine EM-Drive a real aproach to spacecraft propulsion?

Tags: propulsion, engines

I read that the first test was a failure but [another theory](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2218685-nasa-engineers-helical-engine-may-violate-the-laws-of-physics/) says that could be done but it may violate the laws of physics. Is this engine a near future possible propulsion system or is just theory *per se*?

Comment: I thought the EM drive was completely busted--it's just the power running to the motor through Earth's magnetic field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be unworkable.

> If Burns had properly accounted for the total momentum of the box+ring
> system, which must include the energy/momentum of the applied fields
> and forces required to accelerate the individual components (like the
> ring) inside the box, he would have noted that the total momentum
> never changes, even under relativistic transformations and perfectly
> elastic ring/box collisions.

[Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2019/10/17/for-the-last-time-no-a-nasa-engineer-has-not-broken-physics-with-an-impossible-engine/#3afa994c27bf)

Even the designer himself says

> - Basic concept is unproven
> - Has not been reviewed by subject-matter experts
> - Math errors may exist!

[Source](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/10/corkscrewing-bouncy-ion-drive-would-provide-thrust-in-different-universe/)

Both sources say that the energy/momentum of the forces and fields used to accelerate the particles have been neglected. Once this is considered, conservation of momentum still applies.

Comment: Wow quite an extensive article!